CDC footnote symbols in gtsummary (adjust footnote numeric symbols to other in gtsummary object)
I have not been able to find any resources on changing the footnote symbols from the standard numeric format from gtsummary.
I daresay this question doesn't need code?
trial %>%tbl_summary

I have used the set_caption from flextable as a workaround but it is SO cumbersome.
CDC footnote symbols:
Footnotes
Use the following symbols in the order shown to indicate footnotes:
*, †, ‡, §, ¶, #.  If the table requires >6 footnotes, use double (e.g., **, ††) symbols. No space is used between a footnote symbol and the footnote. Place a period at the end of each footnote.
I also don't mind just converting the symbols manually without a helper function, just not perfectly sure where they are stored in the gtsummary object.
Thanks

For the marks, you could use gt::opt_footnote_marks:
(gt::opt_footnote_spec provides options for formatting.)
library(gtsummary)

trial %>% 
  tbl_summary() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  # gt::opt_footnote_marks(marks = "extended")
  gt::opt_footnote_marks(marks = c("*", "†", "‡", "§", "¶", "#"))

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0
